# Xcode: Event not created in Calendar : issue With Timezone?

Tags: ios, ios6, calendar, xcode4.5, eventkit

ddI am facing issue while creating Event in Native CALENDAR, When i pass **event.startDate** anything other than present timestamp... also **event.endDate** not working with different value as below..

```
- (void)createEventInCalendar:(NSString *)calendarType withTitle:(NSString *)eventTitle startDate:(NSString *)stDate endDate:(NSString *)endDATE withNotes:(NSString *)paramNotes addAlarm:(BOOL)alarmNeeded {

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

/* Are there any calendars available to the event store? */
if ([eventStore.calendars count] == 0){
    NSLog(@"No calendars are found.");
}


EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ with Alarm", eventTitle];

//Convert String to DATE
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS"];

NSDate* date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:stDate];
NSDate* date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:endDATE];
//get Difference betwenn 2 DATE Values
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];

event.startDate = date1;
event.endDate   = [date1 initWithTimeInterval:distanceBetweenDates sinceDate:event.startDate];
event.notes = paramNotes;

/* The alarm goes off 2 seconds before the event happens */
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-2.0f];

[event addAlarm:alarm];

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
NSLog(@"Error shows: %@", err);

//Show EVENT EDIT Screen to User.
EKEventEditViewController *controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];

controller.eventStore       = eventStore;
controller.event            = event;
controller.editViewDelegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

#### After debug: Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=4 "The start date must be before the end date." UserInfo=0x223170 {NSLocalizedDescription=The start date must be before the end date.}

where as my Log: ST DATE: 2013-04-25 07:50:00
           & end DATE: 2013-04-29 07:50:00

but EVENT EDIT View shows END DATE value sometime before START DATE.. Its strange.

Can anyone guide me as to how to solve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you verify in debugger that both NSDate values are correct and as you expect them?

Comment: @user826955 but Event is getting END DATE different value.. its taking somevalue  before START DATE. #Strange i think TimeZone issue.. or else issue with **initWithTimeInterval sinceDate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Resolved:

one simple mistake:

```
//get Difference betwenn 2 DATE Values
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
```

it should be

```
//get Difference betwenn 2 DATE Values
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```

Thanks.